# How long does nginx cache when Cache-Control: public

Tags: nginx

How long does nginx cache when Cache-Control: public?

I can see that on a second try it is HIT but I am not able to find out how long it will be cached by nginx with no max-age mentioned?

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/essays levels=2:2:2 keys_zone=essays:125m inactive=7d max_size=10g;
```

Comment: if You mean for how long nginx caches responses from upstream, it depends on `inactive` parameter in `proxy_cache_path` configuration.